# How to set global environment variables using shell script .sh

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have a `.sh` file that locally sets some environment variables in my shell `source my_env.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Setting up local environment variables"
export MY_URL="http://domain.com"
echo "Done"
```

This only sets the variables for that session. Which means that my Python Celery and Supervisor apps which run under a different session cannot access them. I understand I can run them under a user, but I want to know if on Ubuntu using the same shell script above if I can set the variables so they are globally accessible to all applications regardless of users or session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu env variables doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables) the best way would be

> A suitable file for environment variable settings that affect the system as a whole (rather than just a particular user) is /etc/environment

That's assuming you don't mind having them set for the whole machine.

Comment: cd /etc/environment is not a directory on Ubuntu 14

Comment: /etc/environment is not a directory but a file. So open it and add the following line:
MY_URL="...."

Comment: Is there a way my shell script can be executed to copy these variables to that location?

Comment: Depends on how your stuff is run.  According to the doc: "Files with the .sh extension in the /etc/profile.d directory get executed whenever a bash login shell is entered (e.g. when logging in from the console or over ssh".

So if you enter your session from a shell, both will do and profile.d/something would be nice too.

But you have to open a session via ssh or login.

Comment: I was thinking more of running the script once and it added the variables to   environment files i.e. echo out

Comment: Not sure what you mean with you latest question.  I personally wouldn't change the content of an /etc/* file automatically from a session as that might require sudo privileges.

Maybe I missed something in your first question: are both session under the same user ? just 2 different sessions of the same user ?

Answer (score 3):

export your variables in the "/etc/profile".

NOTE: This will make it global for each shell sessions for any user. If you wish to set this variable for every session for a *specific user*, set it in that user's "~/.profile".

Comment: So would I need to add a file to this folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bashrc or zshrc you can source the shell file which sets the environment variables across the sessions or precisely loads all the environment variables in each session.

```
source location/shell-script-sets-env.sh
```

The zshrc and bashrc is available in your $HOME directory. or ~/.zshrc and ~/.bashrc. The current shell can be looked via

```
echo $SHELL
```

Have a look at [setting env permanently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session) for adding it to the profile.