# Using .sh script to set an environment variable

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables

How do I write an .sh script what will globally set an environment variable on Ubuntu 14.

i.e.

```
#!/bin/sh
sets this in to master /etc/environment 
export DB_HOST="123"
```

I am aware I could just run this script and it would set it for the session only!, but what I actually want to do is have the .sh script copy the environment variable to /etc/environment so it is system wide.

OR

is there a way to run the script that it gets set globally?

Comment: Place it in `/etc/profile`

Comment: @anubhava I need a script that does it tho

Comment: @anubhava /etc/profile is a directory not a file, how can I run the script from /etc/profile

Comment: sorry my bad, I mean it is a file not a directory, @Paul Evans says run it from ``/etc/profile`` but I don't understand how the script can be run from that location

Comment: You can place: `. /path/to/script.sh` in `/etc/profile`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set global environment variables using shell script .sh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679154/how-to-set-global-environment-variables-using-shell-script-sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your script from `/etc/profile`, then you'll get what yuo're after.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by run it from location ``/etc/profile`` as that is not a directory but a file.

Comment: @OrbiterFleet yes, so in that file `source` your file, that will `export` your env var