# Setting console env using a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script `setmyenv.sh` as below

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=./abc/tools:$PATH
env | grep PATH
```

When I run it `sh setmyenv.sh`, I could see that the PATH env is set accordingly.

```
PATH=./abc/tools:<whatever my existing PATH setting>
```

However, after my command finish, if I manually type `env | grep PATH` on the console, I got

```
PATH=<whatever my existing PATH setting>
```

I lost the setting that I set using `setmyenv.sh`
It looks like the environement is only set in the lifetime of my script run.

How could I have the environment set sticky even after the script ended. i.e. the purpose of the script is to set the environment.?

P/S: I don't want to set it in my `.bash_profile` nor `etc\profile`, given I only want to set it when needed, by calling `setmyenv.sh`, but not every time I open my console. i.e. not per the answer of [Using .sh script to set an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763384/using-sh-script-to-set-an-environment-variable) or [How to set global environment variables using shell script .sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679154/how-to-set-global-environment-variables-using-shell-script-sh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run

```
sh setmyenv.sh
```

it runs in a separate `sh` process and the changes to PATH are lost when the process finishes.

You need to source your script:

```
source setmyenv.sh
```

or

```
. setmyenv.sh
```

so that it runs in your current shell and all variable assignments are preserved.  Remember not to have any `exit` in `setmyenv.sh` script.  If you do, sourcing the script will terminate your shell.

---

See also:

- [Difference between sourcing a script vs executing it](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip)
- [What's a subshell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138463/do-parentheses-really-put-the-command-in-a-subshell)

Comment: When you run `sh setmyenv.sh` it runs in a separate shell process - which is not the same as a subshell.  A subshell has specific properties, for example local variables can be read in a subshell - they don't have to be exported.  Usually subshells are created using parentheses, for example `( commands )`.